# Is there a bijection between a discrete space infinite and its proper subspace?

Tags: general-topology

I have this question:
if a discrete space is infinite then exists a bijection to its proper subspace??
Is there any theoreme that prove it?

Comment: The proposition you state is sometimes taken to be the definition of infinite. If you have another definition, what is it? If by "space" you mean a topological space then all maps from the space to itself are continuous.

Comment: Yes, I means topological space

Comment: Since the underlying set is infinite there is such a bijection (by definition). It is continuous since all maps are.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Actually, *every* infinite discrete space $X$ is homeomorphic to some proper subspace. Just take $x\in X$ and take *any* bijection from $X$ onto $X\setminus\{x\}$.

Comment: Can you show me a proof of it?

Comment: Of what? You just have to use the fact that **any** function from a discrete space into a topological space is continuous.

Comment: Oh, now I understand. Thank you

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.